# Kubernetes nginx refresh ip address when upstream service IP changes

Tags: nginx, dynamic, service, dns, kubernetes

I am using nginx to proxy requests to multiple Headless services of StatefulSets in a kubernetes cluster. The problem I am having now is that whenever the service IP changes, the nginx does not resolve the service endpoint to updated IP address but still using the outdated cached IP address. I have tried to use the variable in proxy_pass in nginx configuration but it's to no avail at all. Both on my local cluster as well as deployed on AWS EKS. Here is a snippet of my nginx configuration:

```
upstream svc-foo {
  server svc-foo:8080;
  keepalive 1024;
}
server {
  resolver 127.0.0.1 [::1]:5353 valid=10s;
  set $foo http://svc-foo;
  location /foo/ {
    proxy_pass $foo; 
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }
}
```

I expect no downtime when I update the service which causes the service IP to change. Any insight and advice is appreciated.

Comment: Just wondering, if you tried to use the 'resolve' parameter in the nginx upstream config (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server) and if, why it didn't solve your issue

Comment: Oh, just realised that it was introduced in nginx 1.5.12, so you didn't have that option, yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way is to use an DNS sidecar on your nginx pod as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: issue-795
  name: nginx-config
data:
  nginx.conf: |-
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  1;

    events {
      worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
    }

    http {
      server { # php/fastcgi
        listen 80;
        resolver 127.0.0.1:53 ipv6=off valid=10s;
        set $upstream http://backend:8080;
        location / {
              proxy_pass $upstream;
              proxy_http_version 1.1;
         }
      }
    }
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: issue-795
  name: proxy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-config
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          subPath: nginx.conf
      - name: dnsmasq
        image: "janeczku/go-dnsmasq:release-1.0.7"
        args:
          - --listen
          - "127.0.0.1:53"
          - --default-resolver
          - --append-search-domains
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-config
        configMap:
          name: nginx-config
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: issue-795
  name: backend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: backend
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: backend
  namespace: issue-795
spec:
  serviceName: "backend"
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: echoserver
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommand the use of [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resource on Kubernetes with the [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

Its whole purpose is to have a proxy inside your Kubernetes cluster that redirects the traffic to ClusterIP Services.

So you only have one external ELB that redirects all the traffic into your Kubernetes cluster. The Ingress Controller then redirects the traffic to different services.

For more advanced ingress controllers, you can look at [Kong Ingress Controller](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller).

Comment: I tried but it only creates a classic ELB. I need ALB and therefore I use aws-alb-ingress-controller > Ingress > Nginx (NodePort) > svc-<foo>  and the outdated IP problem happens in the Nginx NodePort :(